# Display Image popup with 'option' tag in html&js

Tags: javascript, html

I have one requirement. There is one select box with multiple option as true(multi select). On selection of  any option  in select box I want to display one ‘delete image/link ’ popup corresponding to selected Option. On click, of that that icon corresponding option would be deleted. There is no way in  tag to render image or link.

Can anyone suggest how can I meet above requirement using  js and html.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get a positive response here, please show what you have tried so far.